# Unset session item array from session cart array

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
         [subject] => Computer [price] => 33.00
         [quantity] => 1 
         [total] => 33
         [level] => Array (
            [CSA] => 1
            [CSB] => 2
         )
      )
   )
   [1] => Array (
      [0] => Array (
         [subject] => English
         [price] => 33.00
         [quantity] => 25
         [total] => 825
         [level] => Array (
            [Eintro] => 1
            [EA] =>
            [EB] => 1
         )
      )
   )
```

Guys, I have a session cart array like above. How to remove the item if the subject Computer and price, quantity, total and level which is related to the subject Computer.

I know I have to use unset SESSION. But how to unset the session array only for the Computer row only and doesn't affect other items array in the cart?

```
var_export($session_cart);

array ( 
   0 => array ( 
      0 => array ( 
         'subject' => 'Computer', 
         'price' => '33.00',
         'quantity' => 1,
         'total' => 33, 
         'level' => array ( 
            'CSA' => '1', 
            'CSB' => '2',
         ),
      ),
   ), 
   1 => array ( 
      0 => array ( 
         'subject' => 'English',
         'price' => '33.00',
         'quantity' => 25,
         'total' => 825,
         'level' => array (
            'EA' => '1',
            'EB' => '1',
         ), 
      ), 
   ),
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_export($yourarray);` instead of `print_r($yourarray);` ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the output  of var_export

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the products are in an array in another array, but the idea is that you iterate over all the products and check whether the subject is Computer. If it is, you unset the element of the array by the index you currently are at.

Something like:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['cart']);$i++)
   if ($_SESSION['cart'][$i]['subject'] == 'Computer') unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i])
```